# USB to Virtual Machine XenServer 6.2

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, cups, centos

I've been fighting with this for a while and still nothing. So here is the deal,

I have a XenServer 6.2 machine with many VM. I'm trying to attach the USB Port to the Virtual Machine, to use it with a Print Server using CUPS (CentOS6.4).

This is the architecture;

> XenServer 6.2 (Physic Machine) (Printer Connected via USB)
>   |------- VM (CentOS6.4 need to access the USB Printer)
>   |------- VM
>   |------- VM

Anything would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217605) answer, I have the below details.

> I have fixed this issue using "USB over Network", from
>   [here](http://www.usb-over-network.com). You can easily download the server, install
>   it to the XenServer and then install the client to your VM so you can
>   share the USB devices connected to your physical server to your
>   virtual server.
>
> This works with almost all devices you can imagine. I have even tried
>   to use a webcam and this worked flawless.

I verified the [downloads](http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network-download.html) section and they do have for Linux server/clients.